# running the grpc php plugin on DA Ledger API proto files

Tags: php, grpc, daml

I am building the client-side of my ledger application in PHP.  I have written the DAML code, gone through the [grpc quickstart tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/php.html#install-on-linux), and I ran the command

```
da add ledger-api-protos
```

and now it seems the next step is to run the grpc_php_plugin to covert the .proto files into php classes and functions.  In the quickstart tutorial the command is as follows:

```
protoc --proto_path=examples/protos \
  --php_out=examples/php \
  --grpc_out=examples/php \
  --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin \
  ./examples/protos/helloworld.proto
```

There is only one .proto file.  However, my project folder has an entire directory structure of .proto files! How should the 'protoc' command look for the my project?

I see there are three different main directories: com, google, grpc.  Do I need to include the the .proto files from all three?  I see that many of the .proto files are interdependent.  Are there one or two main .proto files that are needed and will cause all of the others to be pulled in as a result?

Answer (score 2):

```
protoc --proto_path=proto_dir \
  --php_out=xxxxx \
  --grpc_out=xxxxx \
  --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin \
  a.proto b.proto c.proto ...
```

Or refer to how this script does it:
https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/Makefile#L39